# Properties of exported const object map are not defined

Tags: dictionary, typescript

I am trying to simulate map-like behaviour in TypeScript and also get code completion of possible values. I am limited to TypeScript 1.8.

catalog.ts

```
export declare type CATALOG = 'CATALOG1' | 'CATALOG2' | 'CATALOG3';
export const CATALOGS: { [catalog: string]: CATALOG } = {
    CATALOG1: 'CATALOG1',
    CATALOG2: 'CATALOG2',
    CATALOG3: 'CATALOG3'
};
```

example.ts

```
import { CATALOGS } from './catalog';

class MyClass {
    catalogs = CATALOGS;

    constructor() {
        CATALOGS.CATALOG1; // error
        this.catalogs.CATALOG1; // error
    }
}
```

This results in following error:

> Property 'CATALOG1' does not exist on type { [catalog: string]:
>   "CATALOG1" | "CATALOG2" | "CATALOG3" }

Can someone elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing isn't a "map-like behaviour", with a map you'll do something like:

```
CATALOGS.get("CATALOG1");
```

And that's basically what you defined with: `{ [catalog: string]: CATALOG }`.
You can access it like this:

```
let a = CATALOGS["CATALOG1"];
```

If you want to access it as you did, then it should be:

```
interface Catalogs {
    CATALOG1: CATALOG;
    CATALOG2: CATALOG;
    CATALOG3: CATALOG;
}

export const CATALOGS: Catalogs = {
    CATALOG1: 'CATALOG1',
    CATALOG2: 'CATALOG2',
    CATALOG3: 'CATALOG3'
};

let a = CATALOGS.CATALOG1;
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20CATALOG%20%3D%20'CATALOG1'%20%7C%20'CATALOG2'%20%7C%20'CATALOG3'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Catalogs%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG1%3A%20CATALOG%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG2%3A%20CATALOG%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG3%3A%20CATALOG%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20CATALOGS%3A%20Catalogs%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG1%3A%20'CATALOG1'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG2%3A%20'CATALOG2'%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20CATALOG3%3A%20'CATALOG3'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20CATALOGS.CATALOG1%3B))